# Add indent in front of a table in emails using python

Tags: python, html, css, email

I am using python to write emails. The email is written as follows:

```
message_body = """

<html>
</head>
<body><p> Hi,<br><br> This is a test email.</p>
<br><b>Model Performance</b> """ + model_performance_table
```

model_performance_table is a table.
In the email, it looks like below. Is there a way to add intent in front of the table to move it to the right side a little bit?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
message_body = """

<html>
</head>
<body><p> Hi,<br><br> This is a test email.</p>
<br><b>Model Performance</b> <div style=margin-left:15px> """ + model_performance_table + """ </div>"""
```